# How to find the return type in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access application and have problem to find a return type of function. Is there a way to find return type of object? I have type mismatch error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is a built-in function, look at the Access help topic.

If it is a user-defined function, examine its definition.

If you can do neither, use the `TypeName()` function to tell you the data type returned by `YourFunction()`.

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName(YourFunction())
```

If `YourFunction()` returns a variant, `TypeName()` will tell you the variant *subtype*.

Heinzi suggested `VarType()` instead of `TypeName()`.  I habitually reach for `TypeName()` first simply because it's quicker for me, and I'm seldom concerned with its limitations.  However I agree with Heinzi; `VarType()` is better.

JP. offered two other useful suggestions.  First, you can create a simple procedure which declares a *Variant* variable and assign your function's return value to the variable.  Then add a temporary break point (with <kbd>F9</kbd>) on the first `Debug.Print` line, run the procedure, use <kbd>F8</kbd> to move through it line by line, and monitor the variable's value in the Locals Window. (Open that window from the VB editor's main menu.  View -> Locals Window)

```vb
Public Sub examine_YourFunction()
    Dim varFoo As Variant
    Debug.Print "start"
    varFoo = YourFunction()
    Debug.Print varFoo
End Sub
```

And second, for built-in functions that have a return type, you can take advantage of Intellisense to see the return type as you are typing the function name and/or the parameters.

Comment: +1, very good advice. If you need to do the type check at runtime, I'd suggest to use the [VarType function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/vartype-function-HA001228932.aspx) instead (to avoid magic strings).

Comment: + 1 Agree with Heinzi here :)

Comment: You can also declare a Variant variable, run the function and assign it's return value to the variable, then check the variable's value using the Locals Window. And, for built-in functions that have a return type, you can see the return type as you are typing the function name and/or the parameters.

Comment: @HansUp Add it to yours, so it's all in one place.